# How to bind a textblock to an indexer in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following code:

```
    public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.sampleName = new string[10];
        }

        private string[]  sampleName;
        private string _sampleCount;

        public Data obj2 = new Data();

        public string this[int pos] 
        {
            get
            {
                return sampleName[pos];
            }
            set
            {
                sampleName[pos] = value;
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }

       public string sampleCount
       {
            get
            {
                return _sampleCount;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _sampleCount)
                {
                    _sampleCount = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("sampleCount");
                    Console.WriteLine("Test");
                    Console.WriteLine(value);
                    obj2.sampleCount = value;
                    SaveFile.saveFileMain(obj2);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Window2.xaml.cs

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Source = win.DataContext;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("");
myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;         
sampleText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

I want to know how to set the binding path for the sampleName array and also if it is possible to implement OnPropertyChanged method.
P.S The binding code is being triggered by a button click.

Comment: I am thinking why have you used indexer? I have a feeling you can do it much simpler. Tell me how is the `pos` value provided by view?

Comment: I want to make something like " solution explorer "  in visual studio, every project has references, resources, properties ... etc. I want to create something like this to organize my pages. But, in my program I've two categories "samples" and "reports".

Comment: Every user can create unlimited number of pages in either categories, each page may contain a graph, and other data. I am using a textblock as a label showing the name for each page, the textblock shown in the view under samples or reports categories. Everything working fine in runtime, but I want to make the user to be able to save the pages as a project file and be able to load it. So I am using a JSON file for saving the program data.

Comment: Here what I am doing is storing the name for each textblock created ( which is the name for each page - report or sample -)  in a property and then I'll save it to JSON. I am using an indexer because there will be many textblock created by the user, so I want something to organize it and save it in JSON and then load it.